# Why not mutate state directly in componetWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs, setstate

Does React recommend using setState in componentWillReceiveProps? Since componentWillReceiveProps is already occurring just before an update is rendered, I believe updating state in this portion of the lifecycle does not cause a 2nd re-render, it just changes the state along with the new props on the current update. So why not just mutate state directly? For example, why not do this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
  this.state.title = nextProps.title
}
```

What are the drawbacks of the above or the advantages of using setState such as:

```
componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
  this.setState({title: nextProps.title})
}
```

Comment: You can´t set state directly, as other operation may be updating the state at the same time in setState called in other part eventually. You never know if your direct state assignment will happen before or after the asynchronous eventual update. Too weird?

Comment: Yea thats a good point. But assuming you know that the only moment this piece of state matters is during this update, I wonder if theres any performance gain from avoiding this.setState, which is obviously more computationally intensive than just mutating the state

Comment: I would follow the React docs directly and hold off on any assumptions like setState being "obviously more computationally intensive." The [`setState` docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) provide more detail about why you need to call that function, and the [`componentWillReceiveProps` docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) directly say, "perform state transitions using this.setState() in this method."

Comment: I know, its certainly more prudent to do so, but I like to understand where there may be exceptions

Comment: Always call `setState`, never mutate state directly. Don't leave the ReactJS lifecycle.

Comment: Ide like to know specifically why. What are the pros and cons. Dpetrini presented a reason, which is that if another operation caused a state change in the component that state change may still be batched and mutating state here might affect it. But my question then is, what if you know it wont? What if this piece of state doesn't affect any other operation? What are the pros and cons then?